# When location data is missing in CSV file

Tags: csv, shapefile

I have a CSV file with points and their location (in longitude and latitude).
I notice that some longitude and latitude cells have -99 or -999. I am guessing they are null values?
I made it into a shapefile but the location is way off because ArcGIS is still reading these -99 and -999 values.
If I replace these values with <NULL> in the CSV file, would the location of the other values (which are correct) be showing in the right place on the map?

I don't want to delete the records that have these -99 and -999 values although I realize that when a point shapefile is made there is a point (thus, a location) for every record.

I think maybe I could just keep the original CSV file with the -99 and -999 values, make a copy of it, delete these records and make a shapefile out of it (though I have to double check with the person who is also working with me).

Is there another solution though?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about manipulating data

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a shapefile without all the records having a geographic location (lat/long).

You really only have a couple of options to get a shapefile in which all points are correctly placed:

1. Replace `-999` values with the correct latitude and longitude. The primary downside is this will require a bit of research, but sometimes this is readily available (e.g. city location).
2. Delete records with `-999` values. This results in an effectively incomplete shapefile, but consider that many data (e.g. police incidents, illness, GPS records, etc.) are impossible to easily research and replace the geographic data for a point.

Generally, it's a better approach to not include faulty data rather than modifying it, but that depends on the discipline, data, and purpose of your shapefile.

With either approach, the shapefile must be converted again after the CSV is modified; changes to the CSV won't be reflected in a shapefile that has already been made.